# nginx - route to application via path

Tags: nginx

I want to use nginx to route to different application via path. I use the following nginx config (minimal example):

```
server {
    listen 80;

    http://example.com;

    location /myapp/ {
        rewrite ^/myapp/(.*)$ /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:port; 
    }

}
```

The request is working but some application do route back the response to the root. Instead of

```
http://example.com/myapp/*
```

I end up again on

```
http://example.com/*
```

Is there a way, that nginx does route all request from `/myapp/*` to `http://localhost:port/*` (application root) and route back the response to `/myapp/*`

So far I didn't find a solution.

Thanks

Comment: According to what I understood, you might need to use `proxy_redirect` nginx directive: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect